# GLSL: Sample from previous output and not texture2D

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm trying to write a custom shader where I first blur the texture and then run sobel edge finding.

I've got sobel running ok via the following script

```
    vec4 colorSobel = texture2D(texture, uv);
    float bottomLeftIntensity = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(-0.0015625, 0.0020833)).r;
    float topRightIntensity = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(0.0015625, -0.0020833)).r;
    float topLeftIntensity = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(-0.0015625, 0.0020833)).r;
    float bottomRightIntensity = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(0.0015625, 0.0020833)).r;
    float leftIntensity = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(-0.0015625, 0)).r;
    float rightIntensity = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(0.0015625, 0)).r;
    float bottomIntensity = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(0, 0.0020833)).r;
    float topIntensity = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(0, -0.0020833)).r;
    float h = -secondary * topLeftIntensity - coef * topIntensity - secondary * topRightIntensity + secondary * bottomLeftIntensity + coef * bottomIntensity + secondary * bottomRightIntensity;
    float v = -secondary * bottomLeftIntensity - coef * leftIntensity - secondary * topLeftIntensity + secondary * bottomRightIntensity + coef * rightIntensity + secondary * topRightIntensity;

    float mag = length(vec2(h, v));
    //  alpha values removed atm
    if (mag < 0.5) {
        colorSobel.rgb *= (1.0 - 1.0);
        colorSobel.r += 0.0 * 1.0;
        colorSobel.g += 0.0 * 1.0;
        colorSobel.b += 0.0 * 1.0;
        colorSobel.rgb += 1.0 * mag;
    } else { 
        colorSobel.rgb *= (1.0 - 1.0);
        colorSobel.r += 0.0 * 1.0;
        colorSobel.g += 0.0 * 1.0;
        colorSobel.b += 0.0 * 1.0;
        colorSobel.rgb += 1.0 * mag;
    }
    gl_FragColor = colorSobel;
```

However I know it works by sampling the texture via `texture2D`.

If I were to first manipulate the output via a simple script such as this which reduces the colours

```
  vec4 bg = texture2D(texture,uv);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(gb.rgb, 1.0);
  gl_FragColor.r = float(floor(gl_FragColor.r * 0.5 ) / 0.5);
  gl_FragColor.g = float(floor(gl_FragColor.g * 0.5 ) / 0.5);
  gl_FragColor.b = float(floor(gl_FragColor.b * 0.5 ) / 0.5);
```

The output still samples from the texture and ignores the first paint.

Is there a way to sample from the color output rather than using texture2D?
The reason I'm asking is that i'm chaining my shaders at runtime depending on user interaction?

Comment: You've to render the 1st stage to a [Framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) with an attached texture. The original texture is the source of the first stage. The texture attached to the framebuffer is the render target of the first stage and the source of the second (sobel) stage.

Comment: btw. strictly speaking shaders are not scritpts